# How to capture url and open it on an android app?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I am a newbee to programing. I am trying to bundle a webrtc html5 site via crosswalk-project for cross compatibility. My site works on shareable links. Meaning, who ever clicks on the link can join a webrtc session.

I am trying to figure out how to open our site links from email, whatsapp etc with our designated app. I mean any url with mydomain.org/xyz123 should open with our app.

Please could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

intent-filters are your friend.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data
                android:host="mydomain.org"
                android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```